# Visual Studio Code doesn't recognize angular-ui-router.d.ts

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular-ui-router, definitelytyped, visual-studio-code

I'm using Node.js and have installed `angular-ui-router.d.ts` using `tsd` but it seems Visual Studio Code doesn't recognize it.

```
> tsd install angular
> tsd install angular-ui-router
```

I mean in the code below, VS Code doesn't list memebers of `$stateProvider`. (the below code is a javascript code)

```
angular.module("Jimli", ['ui.router'])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.???
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use these `types` in declaration

```
angular.module("Jimli", ['ui.router'])
    .config(($stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider // here, we say what we get
           , $urlRouterProvider: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider) =>  {
        // $stateProvider.???
        $stateProvider.state(...
    })
```

Also, instead of function, I used [arrow function](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html)

Comment: sorry I forgot to notice and updated my question, I'm using Node.js and the code is in `Javascript`.

Comment: Without typescript... now d.ts advantages. Really easy ;)

Comment: Yes and I mean that d.ts is not recognized by VS Code :/

Comment: d.ts stands for definition of a typescript *(representing code not available in Typescript, e.g. extern lib like UI-Router)*. So, I would really strongly suggest: convert your file from **.js** into `.ts`... it will be compiled into JS *(VS will do that if you've installed typescript 1.6.3 plugin)* and you can start to profit from all the power coming with Typescript. hope it helps a bit

Comment: thank you Radim, I'll work around that, it seems delicious suggest

Comment: It is really really very easy to start to use Typescript. Just rename your current .js file into .ts - and it will become Typescript with all support (because all JS code is valid TS code) - and you can step by step introduce advantages of the TS (e.g. types declaration ...) Good luck. Angular, UI-Router and Typescript is ... a superb option ;)